# How can I call a function using parse-server

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm developing a JavaScript web app, and I'm trying to make a "forgot password" feature. I know how to make a function on the server-side, in the Cloud code with Parse function. But what I can't do is pass the object from my controller (in the front-end side). By the way, I'm using ember.js.

I've tried to save ("user.save()") the object (even without changing anything) and then calling Parse.Cloud.AfterSave("user",(request){..}), but I was getting a error. How can I pass an object to the Cloud code?

Comment: First, it is important to notice that Parse Server has a built-in forgot password feature (https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#resetting-passwords). Anyway, if you want to build your custom made one, you can create a cloud code function and then call this cloud code function with `Parse.Cloud.run('theNameOfTheFunction', { user: yourUserVarGoesHere })`.

Comment: Thanks, i knew about the forgot password feature... After i create this function on cloud, how can i access it in the app?

Comment: The code that I sent you is actually the one that you will use in the app in order to call the function.

Comment: Ok got it, in "theNameOfTheFunction", i got to create one in the api code Cloud/Main.js ? Right?

Comment: Yes. I've just added an answer so it can be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `main.js` file, in order to create a cloud code function:

```js
Parse.Cloud.define('resetPassword', async req => {
  console.log(`My user is: ${req.object.getUsername()}`);
  ...
});
```

In your client code, in order to call the cloud code function:

```js
await Parse.Cloud.run('hello', { user: Parse.User.current() });
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, i'm going to test this code, and give you a feedback.

Comment: I'm getting this error "ReferenceError: Parse is not defined" 
When i save a new object, the function Parse.Cloud.afterSave("MyClass" {...}) to manipulate the params...
I tried to use var Parse = require('parse'), but it didn't work.

Comment: I fixed this, but i have another question... I'm passing the email to the Cloud Code. how this function "ParseUser.RequestPasswordResetAsync("email@example.com");" should work? i'm passing the email but its says that i don't have a template for that. I thought that it would send an email to a default Parse Page.

Comment: Can you please open a new question sharing your current code, the error message and the configuration that you are using to initialize Parse?